# Expo keeps crashing with error message - dyld: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate Abort Trap 6

Tags: react-native, expo

Expo was working fine until I did an `npm install native-base --save` and it keeps crashing every time I try to start it. I'm on Mac and have am using my real mobile devices to view the changes in my project.

I've uninstalled the native-base but am not sure how to replace the missing files.

[Refer to error message screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThW0A.png)

Comment: you can see in the error message that this is caused by fsevents. you can refer to this issue on the fsevents repo for help: https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/313

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find a solution for now (thanks to @brentvatne).

I updated the packages, including node:

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
```

And when I started Expo, another error came up - EMFILE: too many open files, watch at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange

The error is caused by Watchman, to which I resolved it with:

```
brew install watchman
```